# Are there any vulnerabillities here? (PHP)

Tags: php, security, text, exploit

So, my script allows people to write content into a .txt file and save it on the server. They can currently write anything they want to. This is the method I'm using to save the file.

```
<?php
$victim = $_POST['victim'];
$user = $_POST['user'];
$comment = $_POST['comment']; 
$IP = $_POST['IP']; 
$data = "$victim | $user | $comment | $IP\n";

//open the file and choose the mode
$fh = fopen($victim.".txt", "a");

fwrite($fh, $data); //close the file fclose($fh); 
print "User Submitted";
echo "URL is mysite.com/".$victim.".txt"
?>
```

My question is - is there anything they could write that would damage the way my server works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. I can send this string as your `victim` POST argument:

```
/var/www/your_website/index.php\0
```

And you'll modify `index.php`. The `\0` makes PHP ignore the `.txt` extension. In `user`, I could send some PHP code and append it into your index page, which is pretty bad.

Comment: Is there any way to fikter that string for suspicious characters, and if there is any, abort the process?

Comment: @JamesPaterson: Don't trust the user's input at all. Assign each file a numeric ID and store it in a folder. Also, why don't you just use a database?

Answer (score 0):

This is an impossible question to answer because there are so many possibilities.  One thing that I see is that someone could upload executable code or script.  If the attacker can then cause the server to process the script in some way it could lead to compromise of the server.  If the text file is ever served out to another user, you have a XSS vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Depending on your server configuration, for example people could provide an URL (for example `http://someotherpage/somepage?`) as the `victim` argument and thereby make PHP open a HTTP (or some other kind of possibly malicious) connection. You propably don't want this to happen.

Comment: Opening an HTTP URL in append mode? That’s not possible.